# How to add custom media element to a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, themes, banner

So I am editing a WordPress theme and the client wants a custom media area. However, I encounter a few problems:

But I don't know how to properly add custom elements to the pages.

If I want to add new elements to a home page, should I do it in a PHP file?
**the current** structure is like this

```
<header> 100% witdh
<content> 80% witdh
<footer> 100% witdh
```

and I have no idea how to add new elements. Also, it would be great if it wasn't be hardcoded (being able to change the media (picture or a video) easily).

The outcome I want

```
<header> 100% witdh
<media> 100% witdh
<content> 80% witdh
<footer> 100% witdh
```

or

```
<header> 100% witdh
  <content> 80% witdh
     <media> 100% witdh
  </content>
<footer> 100% witdh
```

I've been reading guides but they are not providing enough details for me. They just show the code, but the code isn't an issue, the issue is where do I need to write the code - I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved using custom [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/), by custom templates You can customize each page as you see fit by adding different elements to any other page